# Three dots in the settings for VS code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm confused on why i don't see three dots on right hand corner of setting page in VS code.

- **Version:** 1.62.3
- **Date:** 2021-11-17T08:11:14.551Z
- **OS:** Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363

Screenshot of my setting page:
[image: my screenshot]

Screenshot from vs documentation:
[image: vs code documentation]

I'm not sure why i don't see those dots to access `JSON` format of settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dots seem to have disappeared in some version, I don't see them in my instance either. You can however access the `JSON` settings using the `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` command from the command palette after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, that make sense. 
By default i made VS code to open JSON format by pressing "CTRL+," and "CTRL+." for settings page.